# Noise from roof top Make up air exchanger

Tags: hvac

A replacement rooftop make up air unit was installed in our condo in Spring of 2021.  This is the Chicago area.  Soon after a noise that sounded like a recurring timpani drum strike began.  It only affected the two units directly under the installation.  The duration of the noise was 2-5 seconds followed by a quiet interval of 10-20 seconds.  This lasted for several weeks until the weather stayed consistently warm.  In the Fall the same cycle repeated itself stopping when the weather stayed consistently below 50 degrees.  Recently we had a 65 f degree day in mid December.  The noised reoccurred for one day and stopped even though there were a couple of days in the 50’s.  Someone suggested the compressor is unloading to about 40% capacity for mild temps.  Any ideas on ways to reduce this noise?

Comment: I don't think make up air units have compressors, but it may be part of a larger system with a compressor. Just noting this because if only the make up air unit was changed, I wouldn't suspect a compressor to be causing new noises.

Comment: Did they install vibration dampers? The compressor sounds like the problem but without more information I cannot be sure. Posting pictures may help.

Comment: Yhe units cool as well as warm the air depending on the outside temp.  I do not know if vibration dampers were installed.  They out some insulating mats in the unit in response to complaints.  What can you tell me about vibration dampers?  Can they be installed after the initial installation?  Is it difficult?  Thank you for your response.

Comment: What would be the best type of expert to consult with regard to the MAU noise and whether or not noise dampers would help?